# Which part of python do I need to master for penetration testing and security

Tags: python, security, penetration-testing

I want go in network security , and penetration testing field.

Someone told me that I need to know know at least one programming language so that i can code my own tools if required.

I have started with python. But as python is very large i want to which areas of python i need to master for that. Any modules, plugins which can help me.

Comment: [have you tried](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) anything? you should at least list anything you are familiar with, the kind of scripts you want to try to create, do you know how to do these things regardless of language? how much python do you know? you should probably take the basic python tutorials anyway.

Comment: Your question reads like "Hey guys, I want to build a tower, what do I need to know about Hammers and Nails?" - this is way too general to be answered completely. Also, python is not a good choice for this - you will need to know C to even understand most of the security issues in networking, which high-level languages like python just don't have (e.g. buffer overflows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with the other commenters that this is an overly broad question and a duplicate of https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/15705/using-python-for-security, but the best security-related python book i've read is Grey Hat Python. I'd spend a lot of time reading OSS code, and playing with projects like Volatility, W3AF, and Scapy.